# Given a certain regex pattern, re-arrange and manipulate the contents of a cell

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I'm completely new to Macro programming in Excel, and can't find any references to resolve my question.

I have a column of several words in Excel.  If the word is a verb it has an asterisk immediately succeeding the word (without a space).

For example, part of the column looks like this:

```
accuse*
accustomed be*
acid
acidic
acquire*
acre
```

So I need to:

1. Find all instances in which a cell ends with an asterisk, delete that asterisk, and put the word "to" in front of the cell entry.
2. If the word has "be*" then I need to delete the asterisk, the word "be", and put "to be" in the front.

The finished column should look like this:

```
to accuse
to be accustomed
acid
acidic
to acquire
acre
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Is this a one time operation? Why not use Find and Replace (Ctrl+H)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this (select the list then run this)

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim cl As Range

    For Each cl In Selection.Cells
        If Trim(cl) Like "*[*]" Then
            Cl = trim(cl)
            cl = "to " & Left(cl, Len(cl) - 1)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Actual data includes training Linefeed character, sometimes a space before the *, and sometimes  terms after the *

This version deals with these issues

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim r As Range
    Dim str As String, i As Long
    Set r = Selection
    For Each cl In r.Cells
        str = Trim(cl)
        str = Replace(str, " *", "*")
        If Asc(Right$(str, 1)) <= 31 Then
            str = Trim(Left$(str, Len(str) - 1))
        End If
        If str Like "* be[*]*" Then
            i = InStr(str, "*")
            cl = "to be " & Left$(str, i - 4 & Mid$(str, i + 1))
        ElseIf str Like "*[*]*" Then
            i = InStr(str, "*")
            cl = "to " & Left$(str, i - 1) & Mid$(str, i + 1)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This did not work-- none of the cells were edited.  Any ideas why?

Comment: It works for me. There must be something different about your data.  Trailing spaces perhaps?

Comment: Curious... this works on all lists but the one I want.  Is there anyway to automatically sanitize all the data a list such that this macro works?  Also is there anyway to do the number 2 request with a macro?

Comment: What is it about the list that needs sanitizing?  I'll update my answer to deal with trailing spaces. If its other non printable characters we can deal with that too.

Comment: Hmm... I've uploaded the excel spreadsheet here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7cql8nrxvwp5axc/memrise_swahili_template.xls.  I have no idea why this is not working.  Sorry that I'm making this so tedious, but I'd really appreciate the help.